How to use Cairo Graphics in 16 bit color mode?
I am using the Cairo Graphics Library (https://www.cairographics.org/) and I am currently getting my app to export in 8 bits per channel using the following function:
// Write pixel 8-bit
PF_Pixel* sampleIntegral8(PF_EffectWorld& def, int x, int y) {
    return (PF_Pixel*)((char*)def.data +
        (y * def.rowbytes) +
        (x * sizeof(PF_Pixel)));
}

PF_Err cairoCopy8(void* refcon, A_long threadInd, A_long itemNum,
    A_long iterTotal)
{
    cairoRefcon* data = (cairoRefcon*)refcon;
    int i = itemNum;
    PF_Err err = PF_Err_NONE;
    uint32_t* rowP;
    PF_Pixel8* worldPtr = sampleIntegral8(data->output, 0, i);
    rowP = (uint32_t*)(data->data + i * data->stride);
    for (int x = 0; x < data->output.width; x++) {
        worldPtr->alpha = rowP[x] >> 24;
        if (worldPtr->alpha)
        {
            float rf = A_u_char(rowP[x] >> 16) / (float)worldPtr->alpha;
            float gf = A_u_char(rowP[x] >> 8) / (float)worldPtr->alpha;
            float bf = A_u_char(rowP[x] >> 0) / (float)worldPtr->alpha;
            worldPtr->red = A_u_char(rf * PF_MAX_CHAN8);
            worldPtr->green = A_u_char(gf * PF_MAX_CHAN8);
            worldPtr->blue = A_u_char(bf * PF_MAX_CHAN8);
        }
        worldPtr++;
    }

    return err;
}

This is taken from the example located here: https://github.com/nithishakumar/Pattern-After-Effects-Plugin/blob/main/Pattern.cpp
I have tried to adapt this code to export in 16 bit (my calculations should be correctly done in 16 bit) by using the following code:
PF_Pixel16* sampleIntegral16(PF_EffectWorld& def, int x, int y) {
    return (PF_Pixel16*)((char*)def.data +
        (y * def.rowbytes) +
        (x * sizeof(PF_Pixel16)));
}

PF_Err cairoCopy16(void* refcon, A_long threadInd, A_long itemNum,
    A_long iterTotal)
{
    cairoRefcon* data = (cairoRefcon*)refcon;
    int i = itemNum;
    PF_Err err = PF_Err_NONE;
    uint32_t* rowP;
    PF_Pixel16* worldPtr = sampleIntegral16(data->output, 0, i);
    rowP = (uint32_t*)(data->data + i * data->stride);
    for (int x = 0; x < data->output.width; x++) {
        worldPtr->alpha = rowP[x] >> 24;
        if (worldPtr->alpha)
        {
            float rf = A_u_char(rowP[x] >> 16) / (float)worldPtr->alpha;
            float gf = A_u_char(rowP[x] >> 8) / (float)worldPtr->alpha;
            float bf = A_u_char(rowP[x] >> 0) / (float)worldPtr->alpha;
            worldPtr->red = A_u_char(rf * PF_MAX_CHAN16);
            worldPtr->green = A_u_char(gf * PF_MAX_CHAN16);
            worldPtr->blue = A_u_char(bf * PF_MAX_CHAN16);
        }
        worldPtr++;
    }

    return err;
}

However, this isn't working. I suspect it's because it requires a different bit-shifting than the 8-bit but bit-shifting is something I just don't understand. Perhaps it is not that though.
Can anyone help me figure out what' wrong and help me make this 8-bit function work for 16-bit?
Thanks

'This isn't working' is of no help. Please explain exactly what goes wrong when you run this code.

It's a bit confusing. In non-working version could you clarify how many bits per channel there are in the input and output. Is it 16 bits in both, or are you attempting a 16 bit to 8 bit conversion or a 8 bit to 16 bit conversion?

A_u_char(rf * PF_MAX_CHAN16) seems likely to be truncating to 8-bits

The A_u_char part is weird. It does not appear in the code you have copied this code from. What is it? Why is it there?

You say you are using cairo. How? Nothing here looks like it is from cairo. I do not even know what cairoRefcon is. And which part of this is 8 bit / 16 bit? You replaced some 8s with 16s, but... what is PF_MAX_CHAN16 and where does it come from? What is PF_Pixel16? All of those do not come from cairo.
